# Can someone help me to send mail in PHP

Tags: php, email

```
<?php
require("./PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    global $error;

    $from  = $_REQUEST['from'];
    $from_name = $_REQUEST['from_name'];
    $subject  = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $body = $_REQUEST['body'];
    $is_gmail  = $_REQUEST['is_gmail'] =true;
    $to  = $_REQUEST['to'];
  $to  = "defaultemail@live.in"; // used for testing only
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    if ($is_gmail) {
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.ks101.fdsfd.eu';
        $mail->Username = 'testing@edsfdsd.de';  
        $mail->Password = "pass";   
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    } else {
        $mail->Host = SMTPSERVER;
        $mail->Username = SMTPUSER;  
        $mail->Password = SMTPPWD;
    }        
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        echo(false);
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        echo(true);
        return true;
    }
?>
```

I show the following code to hosting provider and they tell me it should work. I try to upload it but it's not worked.

I got the error when I try on the actual sever where site should be (maybe PHP server).

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  stream_socket_enable_crypto() [<a href='streams.crypto'>streams.crypto</a>]: this stream does not support SSL/crypto in <b>/home/www/web420/html/test/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php</b> on line <b>197</b><br />
SMTP -> ERROR: RSET failed: 
<br />Language string failed to load: tls
```

When I try on my server I got error for same code (IIS 7)

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  stream_socket_enable_crypto() [<a href='streams.crypto'>streams.crypto</a>]: this stream does not support SSL/crypto in <b>C:\inetpub\vhosts\test.com\subdomains\test\httpdocs\appbounce\PHPMailer\class.smtp.php</b> on line <b>197</b><br />
```

I don't know what is the server used by the website.  I got different-2 errors. Please someone verify that if their is a problem in my code. What exactly I need to do.

thanks

Comment: Does `mail();` work? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Hey @Michas Could you tell me how I can set password with it.

Comment: If You are lucky and mail is configured on PHP server, it works without password.

Answer (score 0):

some quick tips

Add this

```
$mail->Port = 465;
```

change this

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
```

if both of not work.... then problem with router level authentication at hosting part

Comment: you are right. it's work for gmail but not for domain account I have.

Comment: contact to your hosting provider... this is definitely not a problem of script....

Comment: Sir,I have contact them and spent my 2 days with it but they still not help me with the code. They still have many idea but not solution about the problem their customer have.

Comment: do one thing, try with simple PHP mail function for other user than gmail, may be still at you domain the seup the POP3 protocol for mail instead of SMTP... are you on shared hosting OR dedicated hosting ?